# Play h264 raw stream with gst-play at certain framerate

Tags: gstreamer

I have a raw stream in `h264` format. Now I want to play the stream at 30 FPS. Is there any way I can do that with gst-play or gst-launch playbin?

It seems that `playbin` has no Properties for frame rate.

```
gst-launch playbin uri=file:///path/to/teststreame.h264
```

How can I control the playback frame rate for the above pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `playbin` you'll probably have to write an application, use the `video-sink` attribute of `playbin`, and pass it another bin that uses `videorate` within.  That bin would be something like this:

`videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! autovideosink`

If you want to run from the command line you can use gst-launch and the videorate element along with some caps to control the framerate.  The downside is you'll need to write out the full pipeline yourself.

`gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=/tmp/test.h264 ! video/x-h264 ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=30/1 ! autovideosink`